# Execute .sql file from file system through SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to execute .sql scripts that are on my hard drive through SQL Server Agent without having to use `xp_cmdshell` or `sql_cmd`? Using SQL Server 2008.

I am looking for a simple solution like:

```
include 'c:\mysql\test.sql'
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've accepted one answer and never up-voted any?

Comment: @Aaron - You need 15 rep to vote up.

Comment: @Martin ok, but wouldn't they be closer if they accepted more than one of their questions so far?

Comment: @Martin or another up-vote on their question (guilty as charged). Hopefully they will now use that rep to go reward folks that have answered their past questions.

Comment: @Aaron I'll be more mindful of this. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using a Windows scheduled task instead of SQL Server Agent. No matter how you read files off disk, it's going to come with the same type of restrictions preventing you from using `xp_cmdshell` or `sqlcmd` (assuming the reason isn't just fear).

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your response. I'd like to use SQL server agent because of the additional functionality (I can break down the running of my sql into steps and email out upon completion.) So are you saying that there isn't a way to just execute the sql through the agent without using xp_cmdshell? Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server needs some way to find the file - by default the file system is pretty much off-limits. While you still haven't explained why you don't want to use `xp_cmdshell` or `sqlcmd`, perhaps you're going about it the wrong way. Instead of SQL Server going and finding your .sql script, why not automate the part about getting the .sql script into SQL Server whenever it has changed? Why does it have to be a .sql script and not a stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have several sql scripts that I want to maintain on the disk. Having the stored procedures existing as steps in the agent adds a maintenance step that I am trying to avoid. I am a total nube in this area, I was not aware I could automategetting the scripts into the agent when they are changed. This sounds like a solutionthat might work for me.

Comment: Well, you don't "get the scripts into the agent"... how are the .sql files changing in the first place? There is a maintenance step there, whether it is modifying a stored procedure or modifying a .sql file. Personally it makes a whole lot more sense to store your database code in the database than in a .sql file on the file system, especially for things that aren't one-time tasks (and that you want to try to run from within SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

Within modern versions of SSMS you get to pick .sql files and import them directly into the step (effectively creating a copy that will be run instead).
As Aaron says, better to keep the code safely in the server & backed up.

You can always keep a script which creates the job & steps in a file, so that there is a one-shot creation (or in case you need to deploy across multiple servers).
If editing steps in the agent dialog is a frustration, then perhaps this is a different alternative. Unless you make efforts to preserve it, you will lose history on if you simply recreate the job each time though.

if it's just that the script is frequently amended with changes that need to be tested then you could look at putting the xp_cmdshell/sqlcmd into the job, although it makes it *much* more fragile wrt file locations, access rights & potentially makes your error handling a bit more work.

You will need to check filesystem access is enabled - many sysadmins prefer this to be disabled, due to the risks of something uncontrolled being run.
So don't just assume it will work on servers that aren't yours!